# cv_bridge::Exception bayer_rggb8 vs 8UC3

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm publishing `/camera/image_raw` of type `sensor_msgs/Image` from [PointgreyDriver](http://wiki.ros.org/pointgrey_camera_driver) :

```
image_transport::SubscriberStatusCallback cb = boost::bind(&PointGreyCameraNodelet::connectCb, this);
it_pub_ = it_->advertiseCamera("image_raw", 5, cb, cb);
```

On the other hand I'm subscribing to that topic:

```
 this->sub = new image_transport::Subscriber(this->imageTransport->subscribe("/camera/image_raw",1000,&p_vision_apriltags::callback,this));
imgTmp = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg,sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_8UC3);
```

The error I'm getting is an exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv_bridge::Exception'
  what():  [bayer_rggb8] is a color format but [8UC3] is not so they must have the same OpenCV type, CV_8UC3, CV16UC1 ....
[AprilTagsDetector-1] process has died [pid 29207, exit code -6, cmd /home/jaouadros/catkin_ws/devel/lib/p_vision_apriltags/p_vision_apriltags __name:=AprilTagsDetector __log:=/home/jaouadros/.ros/log/da606018-a91e-11e7-80aa-0024d7d045f0/AprilTagsDetector-1.log].
log file: /home/jaouadros/.ros/log/da606018-a91e-11e7-80aa-0024d7d045f0/AprilTagsDetector-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
```

When I change `TYPE_8UC3` to `bgr8` it shows frames with random uniform colors.

What types should I be using?
normally `TYPE_8UC3` works with `image_raw` !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272294/cv_bridge::exception-bayer_rggb8-vs-8uc3/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2017-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_8UC3 is not a color format, it is a data type with 3 channels of 8 bits each (but with no information of what each channel mean), so cv_bridge::toCvCopy doesn't know who to transform from bayer_rggb8 color format.

I assume that what you really want is to transform the original image received in bayer_rggb8 format to the more commonly used BGR8 format.

In that case try the following:

```
 imgTmp = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
```

Now, BGR8 **is** a color format, it also has 3 channels of 8 bits each, but now you know that the first channel corresponds to Blue, the second corresponds to Green and the third corresponds to Red.

If by doing this you get random uniform colors, then make sure that the original image published by the driver is actually in bayer_rggb8 format.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-10-05**:
BGR8 gives me a uniform color each frame. How can I make sure that it is of type `bayer_rggb8`? rostopic info `/camera/image_raw` doesn't give much information?

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2017-10-05**:
You should check the specifications of your camera, which camera are you using?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-10-06**:
I'm using this camera `Blackfly 0.9 MP Color GigE PoE`